# TableSorter loses header text

Tags: asp.net, jquery, tablesorter

I'm using [**tablesorter**](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) in an `asp:GridView` and works fine but this been bother me for some time

**Every time there is a button action** (firing up a call to the server, refreshing the page), **table sorter loses the headers** as you can see by the 2 images below:

before refresh:

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-09-17_1504.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-09-17_1504.png)

after refresh:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea of if this might be a bug, or something on my end just for the behavior of it? Maybe someone already crossed this problem before

Comment: Can you post the code for creating the table and adding the tablesorter?

Comment: JamesMLV it's a simple GridView that is filled up with a DataSet, no code needed.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to specify a custom header, and then put a conditional in your:

```
OnRowCreated
```

Event checking to see if you're currently processing the header row, and if so, populate with your custom header. This gets around the loss of the auto created headers.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using Rad Controls, which most likely is using ajax on postback.  When the dom rebuilds, your jQuery tablesorter plugin loses it's binding on those recreated elements.

More about it here:
[jquery tablesorter + ajax div content update problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718307/jquery-tablesorter-ajax-div-content-update-problem)

Comment: I just kept the id's, I'm using a normal GridView now, as I state in the question (first line), as Rad controls I had much more trouble and took forever to render.